# Scanning Documents from feeder using NTwain

Tags: c#, scanning, twain

I'm trying to use the ADF feature on a Canon TR8520 and can't seem to find how to do it.

I can scan documents using the flatbed with no problems and I've found the Capabilities Properties that seem to have something to do with it:

```
    twainVM._session.CurrentSource.Capabilities.CapFeederEnabled.SetValue(BoolType.True);
    twainVM._session.CurrentSource.Capabilities.CapDuplexEnabled.SetValue(BoolType.True);
```

but these don't seem to enable the feeder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research and annoyance I finally gave up on using NTwain and moved to Twaindotnet. Haven't had any problems with it so far so I'd recommend this to anyone having problems with NTwain.